# Power query advance editor ERROR - PowerBI to Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Below code was auto generated in Power BI and wanted to duplicate it in excel.
However there is an Expression Error "THe import Html.Table matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?".

I copied and paste the code from PowerBI advance editor M code to Excel advance editor below

```
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("http://edge.pse.com.ph/disclosureData/dividends_and_rights_info_form.do"),
    #"Extracted Table From Html" = Html.Table(Source, {{"Company Name", "DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR > :nth-child(1)"}, {"Type of Security", "DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR > :nth-child(2)"}, {"Type of Dividend", "DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR > :nth-child(3)"}, {"Dividend Rate", "DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR > :nth-child(4)"}, {"Ex-dividend Date", "DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR > :nth-child(5)"}, {"Record Date", "DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR > :nth-child(6)"}, {"Payment date", "DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR > :nth-child(7)"}, {"Circular Number", "DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR > :nth-child(8)"}}, [RowSelector="DIV[id='dataList'] > TABLE.list:nth-child(7) > TBODY > TR"]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Extracted Table From Html",{{"Company Name", type text}, {"Type of Security", type text}, {"Type of Dividend", type text}, {"Dividend Rate", type text}, {"Ex-dividend Date", type date}, {"Record Date", type date}, {"Payment date", type date}, {"Circular Number", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Entire report is created in excel.
Prefer to fetch the table in excel as some features required are not available in powerBI.

Answer (score 0):

Although PowerQuery and PowerBI are very similar, some of the code commands differ.

Instead of copy-pasting the powerBI code directly into PQ, I would have recommended going through (at least some) of the steps directly in PQ. Assuming you have Excel 2016 or later, I believe the following code should work in PQ for you:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("http://edge.pse.com.ph/disclosureData/dividends_and_rights_info_form.do")),
    Data = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data,{{"Company Name", type text}, {"Type of Security", type text}, {"Type of Dividend", type text}, {"Dividend Rate", type text}, {"Ex-Dividend Date", type date}, {"Record Date", type date}, {"Payment Date", type date}, {"Circular Number", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

If you have an older version of PQ, you may need to walk through the manual steps of connecting to the website in order for the correct code to be generated. (I don't know if the web-connection code, which my PQ generated, is viable in older versions of PQ.)

Comment: I did it also in excel PQ but unable to load the data in excel sheet.. are u able to load the table? Btw im using office 365. I think I have the latest because I also repair the office app after I faced this problem. Office apps Icon, including excel, is the latest as well

Comment: @LealPERMALINO That's odd. I tried copy/pasting the code I had included into the Advanced Editor, then loading, and it error-ed out after the preview rows. When I tried to go make adjustments, I lost the first visible row from the first step, which allowed that expansion, and haven't been able to get it back for that web page. I tried with  the halts and suspensions list from a new web query and could get it to load just fine. Then tried refreshing it some time later, and now it keeps hitting `An unknown error occurred when navigating to the web page`